# Getting strange characters when try to get location info with google's geocode api

Tags: android, google-maps, character-encoding

In my app a try to get location names via tapping on google map.
Everything works fine except for the character encoding.

My output is like:

**1144 Budapest, Ond vezÃ©r Ãºtja 35, Hungary**

How could i set character encoding to get the correct response like:

**1144 Budapest, Ond vezér útja 35, Hungary**

I tried with `.setHeader("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");`
but not working this way.

Code:

```
public static JSONObject getLocationInfo(double lat, double lng) {

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + lat + "," + lng + "&sensor=true");
        httpGet.setHeader("Accept-Charset","utf-8");

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();



        try {
            response = client.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
            int b;
            while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                stringBuilder.append((char) b);
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return jsonObject;
    }
```

**E D I T:**

I made this work with:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
```

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Have you tried with `ISO-8859-2`?

Comment: Your edit worked for me perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
    stringBuilder.append((char) b);
}
```

That's effectively using ISO-8859-1.

Instead, you should create an `InputStreamReader` from the `InputStream`, specifying UTF-8 as the encoding (as that's what you say you accept), and then read from that. You could read from it directly, or use something like [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and `CharStreams.toString`:

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String text = CharStreams.toString(reader);
```